# How to implement pagination over cards using table method pagination

Tags: javascript, angular

i'm using table pagination template to make a pagination over cards. the pagination seems working but data isn't loaded.

This is my html component : If i change my datasource2 inside ngFor, the data is loaded but with no pagination rules.

```
<mat-card  *ngFor="let item of dataSource2" >
             <!--cart header-->
    
             <mat-card-header>
                <div  mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
                <mat-card-title > <a href="" > {{item.title}} </a> </mat-card-title>
                <mat-card-subtitle > {{item.subtitle}}  </mat-card-subtitle>
                </mat-card-header>
  
                <img mat-card-image src="{{ item.imgsrc }}"  alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu" >   
    
                 <mat-card-content> <p>  {{item.content}} </p>  </mat-card-content>    
                
                  <mat-card-actions>   
                    <button mat-button>LIKE</button>          
                     <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
                </mat-card-actions>
                             
     </mat-card>
                

 <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
    
    </div>
```

the component ts :

```
    export class CardsComponent implements AfterViewInit {
     
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'title', 'subtitle', 'content','imgsrc'];
      dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
    
    
      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.dataSource2.paginator = this.paginator;
      
      } 
    
    }
    
    const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] =   [ 
      {position: 1, title: 'Shiba Inu Yes', subtitle:'Dog Breed',content:'The Shiba Inu is the smallest' , imgsrc:'https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg'},
      {position: 2, title: 'Shiba Inu', subtitle:'Dog Breed',content:'The Shiba Inu is the smallest' , imgsrc:'https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg'},
      {position: 3, title: 'Shiba Inu', subtitle:'Dog Breed',content:'The Shiba Inu is the smallest' , imgsrc:'https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg'},
      {position: 4, title: 'Shiba Inu', subtitle:'Dog Breed',content:'The Shiba Inu is the smallest' , imgsrc:'https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg'},
      {position: 5, title: 'Shiba Inu', subtitle:'Dog Breed',content:'The Shiba Inu is the smallest' , imgsrc:'https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg'},
      {position: 6, title: 'Shiba Inu', subtitle:'Dog Breed',content:'The Shiba Inu is the smallest' , imgsrc:'https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg'},
      {position: 7, title: 'Shiba Inu', subtitle:'Dog Breed',content:'The Shiba Inu is the smallest' , imgsrc:'https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg'},
      
    ];
    
    export interface PeriodicElement {
      
      position: number;
      title:  string;
      subtitle: string;
      content: string;
     imgsrc: string;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a custom card component that I was displaying about 500 of them on the same page. I used this post to figure out how to paginate them.

[how can use mat-paginator for paging a custom card-based component into parent component view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70543443/how-can-use-mat-paginator-for-paging-a-custom-card-based-component-into-parent-c/70551270#70551270)

Basically just have the paginator standalone. Slice your dataset within *ngFor and set all of the paginator attributes like pageIndex, pageSize, and length.