# Angular material pagination with different table library

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, pagination

So, I am using this different table library for my table and created a custom paginator. I want to use this paginator-goto in the table. How can i use the paginator for table to work.
The table is a custom table library and therefore I am not sure how to use the dataSource with the pagination. I just need pagination to response when i click next or previous.
here is the pagination demo. `https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-paginator-with-goto-5fxwvm?file=src/app/mat-paginator-goto/mat-paginator-goto.component.html`

Comment: generally you can use [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70543443/how-can-use-mat-paginator-for-paging-a-custom-card-based-component-into-parent-c/70551270#70551270) if you has a custom paginator check the name of the variables

Comment: If you use a template reference variable (the #paginator in the link), you can access to all the variables and function of the MatPaginatorGotoComponent. So you can use `<tru-core-table ... [rows]="tableExampleRows|slice:paginator.pageIndex*paginator.pageSize):((paginator.pageIndex+1)*paginator.pageSize)" >`

Comment: see a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-paginator-with-goto-7e3jbd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with a app-table (I can not find your `tru-core-table` component. NOTE: becareful, I forget a **(** in my before coment

Comment: I wrote an answer to how change the "<" and ">". Well, in the examle I use a customPaginatorIntl. Really only change the .css you can get it -instead use as content `attr(aria-label)`, you can "hardcode" the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the "labels" of < and >, the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples) (see the example of internationalization) indicate how change the **"tooltip"**

Adding a MyCustomPaginatorIntl

```
export class MyCustomPaginatorIntl implements MatPaginatorIntl {
  changes = new Subject<void>();

  firstPageLabel = "First page"
  itemsPerPageLabel = "Items per page:"
  lastPageLabel = "Last page:"

  nextPageLabel = "Next";
  previousPageLabel = "Previous";
  getRangeLabel(page: number, pageSize: number, length: number): string {
    if (length === 0) {
      return "Page 1 of 1";
    }
    const amountPages = Math.ceil(length / pageSize);
    return `Page ${page + 1} of ${amountPages}`;
  }
}
```

And use as provider -you can do it in app.module or in your component

```
providers:[{provide:MatPaginatorIntl,useClass:MyCustomPaginatorIntl}],
```

But if we want to change the "<" and the ">" we need work with the class

We can write in our styles.css -not work if we don't use a styles for all the aplication

```
.mat-paginator-navigation-next .mat-button-wrapper,
.mat-paginator-navigation-previous .mat-button-wrapper
{
  color:transparent!important;
}
.mat-paginator-navigation-previous
{
  width:5em!important;;
}
.mat-paginator-navigation-next::after{
  content:attr(aria-label);
  margin-left:-2em;
}
.mat-paginator-navigation-previous::after{
  content:attr(aria-label);
  margin-left:-2em;
}
```

In the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-paginator-with-goto-7e3jbd?file=src%2Fstyles.css) are an example of it's using the ashraful Islam's custom paginator

**Update** well when we change the dataSource, we ned "manually update" the paginator. Well it's not different to another one. We can use ViewChild to get the MatPaginatorGotoComponent

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginatorGotoComponent) paginator
```

And, when we change the data we can use, e.g.

```
this.paginator.pageIndex=0;
this.paginator.goTo=1
```

Or

```
if (this.paginator.pageIndex*this.paginator.pageSize>this.data.length)
{
    const pageIndex=Math.ceil(this.data.length / this.paginator.pageSize)-1
    this.paginator.pageIndex=pageIndex
    this.paginator.goTo=pageIndex+1
}
```

Comment: Awsome, Thanks a lot @Eliseo

Comment: I see its working in stackblitz but when i implemented on mine, it only changes the tooltip, still showing < >. I used exactly whats here

Comment: see that the .css should be in "styles.css" (or in styles.scss) -the file you indicate in your angular.json-

Comment: Its mat-paginator-goto.component.scss . If i chnage the style.scss it will affect everywhere i used mat-paginator. It will break some codes. So, I wanted to only change this paginator

Comment: you can preceding all the .css with mat-paginator-goto, e.g. `mat-paginator-goto .mat-paginator-navigation-previous`... I updated the stackblitz to see

Comment: awesome, thank you for your help.

Comment: adding data and whenever I change data using a dropdown, and if i am on lets say 5th page, and data reduces the page index dosent change

Comment: Hey @ACE, can you make a stackblitz? BTW:In this [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787342/how-can-i-style-mat-paginator-angular-as-shown/70962395#70962395) I take another approach to make a really custom-paginator

Comment: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-paginator-with-goto-7e3jbd?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

Comment: I'm in hurry, I update the answer, see that you can access to all the public properties of your matPaginatorComponent if you use a ViewChild

Comment: app.html `<button (click)="re()">
reduce</button>` app.ts `re() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      this.data.pop();
    }` change the page to the last page, now click reduce, the dropdown stays in 5th page, thats what i want to reset so that when data reduces it gets to first page

Comment: you need check if you're in a page greater than number of pages. I forked the stackblitz in https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-paginator-with-goto-mj2sov. NOTE: In the update of the answer I miss, we need less 1 the result of Math.ceil, just corrected

Comment: how can we add right and left arrow on next and prev, for example: <- prev [] next ->, if we use can use a html elements, for exmaple: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} />