# How can I customize my mat paginator in angular 8 it includes round shaped buttons?

Tags: json, angular, angular-material, customization

I want to Customize the mat paginator in Angular 8 to include round-shaped buttons., I am not able to make any changes in the default in-built mat paginator.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787342/how-can-i-style-mat-paginator-angular-as-shown

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Eliseo thanks for  help but it is not what i m exactly looking for will you please suggest me some other useful  links.

Comment: @akashtyagi, sorry, I don't know where are some exactly you're looking for, the link it's about an example that you can change to adapt to your requirements.