# Customise Angular Material pagination

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-pagination, angular-material-paginator

I am working on Angular Material custom pagination.
If the numbers are more than 5, then I need to see `1 2 ... 4 5`, if it is only 3 then `1 2 3`, if it is 4 then `1 2 ... 4` but now I am getting as `1 2 ...`.

Any help on this?

HTML:

```
<mat-paginator
    style-paginator
    showFirstLastButtons
    [length]="dataSource.data.length"
    [pageSize]="3"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 5, 10, 20]"
  >
 </mat-paginator>
```

TS:

```
import {
  ElementRef,
  AfterViewInit,
  Directive,
  Host,
  Optional,
  Renderer2,
  Self,
  ViewContainerRef,
  Input,
} from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatButton } from '@angular/material/button';

interface PageObject {
  length: number;
  pageIndex: number;
  pageSize: number;
  previousPageIndex: number;
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[style-paginator]',
})
export class StylePaginatorDirective {
  private _pageGapTxt = '...';
  private _rangeStart: number;
  private _rangeEnd: number;
  private _buttons = [];
  private _curPageObj: PageObject = {
    length: 0,
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 0,
    previousPageIndex: 0,
  };

  @Input()
  get showTotalPages(): number {
    return this._showTotalPages;
  }
  set showTotalPages(value: number) {
    this._showTotalPages = value % 2 == 0 ? value + 1 : value;
  }
  private _showTotalPages = 2;

  get inc(): number {
    return this._showTotalPages % 2 == 0
      ? this.showTotalPages / 2
      : (this.showTotalPages - 1) / 2;
  }

  get numOfPages(): number {
    return this.matPag.getNumberOfPages();
  }

  get lastPageIndex(): number {
    return this.matPag.getNumberOfPages() - 1;
  }

  constructor(
    @Host() @Self() @Optional() private readonly matPag: MatPaginator,
    private vr: ViewContainerRef,
    private ren: Renderer2
  ) {
    //to rerender buttons on items per page change and first, last, next and prior buttons
    this.matPag.page.subscribe((e: PageObject) => {
      if (
        this._curPageObj.pageSize != e.pageSize &&
        this._curPageObj.pageIndex != 0
      ) {
        e.pageIndex = 0;
        this._rangeStart = 0;
        this._rangeEnd = this._showTotalPages - 1;
      }
      this._curPageObj = e;

      this.initPageRange();
    });
  }

  private buildPageNumbers() {
    const actionContainer = this.vr.element.nativeElement.querySelector(
      'div.mat-paginator-range-actions'
    );
    const nextPageNode = this.vr.element.nativeElement.querySelector(
      'button.mat-paginator-navigation-next'
    );
    const prevButtonCount = this._buttons.length;

    // remove buttons before creating new ones
    if (this._buttons.length > 0) {
      this._buttons.forEach((button) => {
        this.ren.removeChild(actionContainer, button);
      });
      //Empty state array
      this._buttons.length = 0;
    }

    //initialize next page and last page buttons
    if (this._buttons.length == 0) {
      let nodeArray =
        this.vr.element.nativeElement.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[2]
          .childNodes;
      setTimeout(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < nodeArray.length; i++) {
          if (nodeArray[i].nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
            if (nodeArray[i].innerHTML.length > 100 && nodeArray[i].disabled) {
              this.ren.setStyle(
                nodeArray[i],
                'background-color',
                'rgba(190, 130, 130, 1)'
              );
              this.ren.setStyle(nodeArray[i], 'color', 'white');
              this.ren.setStyle(nodeArray[i], 'margin', '.5%');
            } else if (
              nodeArray[i].innerHTML.length > 100 &&
              !nodeArray[i].disabled
            ) {
              this.ren.setStyle(
                nodeArray[i],
                'background-color',
                'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
              );
              this.ren.setStyle(nodeArray[i], 'color', 'white');
              this.ren.setStyle(nodeArray[i], 'margin', '.5%');
            } else if (nodeArray[i].disabled) {
              this.ren.setStyle(nodeArray[i], 'background-color', 'lightgray');
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.numOfPages; i++) {
      if (i >= this._rangeStart && i <= this._rangeEnd) {
        this.ren.insertBefore(
          actionContainer,
          this.createButton(i, this.matPag.pageIndex),
          nextPageNode
        );
      }

      if (i == this._rangeEnd) {
        this.ren.insertBefore(
          actionContainer,
          this.createButton(this._pageGapTxt, this._rangeEnd),
          nextPageNode
        );
      }
    }
  }

  private createButton(i: any, pageIndex: number): any {
    const linkBtn: MatButton = this.ren.createElement('button');
    this.ren.addClass(linkBtn, 'mat-mini-fab');
    this.ren.setStyle(linkBtn, 'margin', '1%');
    this.ren.setStyle(linkBtn, 'background-color', 'white');

    const pagingTxt = isNaN(i) ? this._pageGapTxt : +(i + 1);
    const text = this.ren.createText(pagingTxt + '');

    this.ren.addClass(linkBtn, 'mat-custom-page');
    switch (i) {
      case pageIndex:
        this.ren.setAttribute(linkBtn, 'disabled', 'disabled');
        break;
      case this._pageGapTxt:
        let newIndex = this._curPageObj.pageIndex + this._showTotalPages;

        if (newIndex >= this.numOfPages) newIndex = this.lastPageIndex;

        if (pageIndex != this.lastPageIndex) {
          this.ren.listen(linkBtn, 'click', () => {
            console.log('working: ', pageIndex);
            this.switchPage(newIndex);
          });
        }

        if (pageIndex == this.lastPageIndex) {
          this.ren.setAttribute(linkBtn, 'disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        break;
      default:
        this.ren.listen(linkBtn, 'click', () => {
          this.switchPage(i);
        });
        break;
    }

    this.ren.appendChild(linkBtn, text);
    //Add button to private array for state
    this._buttons.push(linkBtn);
    return linkBtn;
  }
  //calculates the button range based on class input parameters and based on current page index value. Used to render new buttons after event.
  private initPageRange(): void {
    const middleIndex = (this._rangeStart + this._rangeEnd) / 2;

    this._rangeStart = this.calcRangeStart(middleIndex);
    this._rangeEnd = this.calcRangeEnd(middleIndex);

    this.buildPageNumbers();
  }

  //Helper function To calculate start of button range
  private calcRangeStart(middleIndex: number): number {
    switch (true) {
      case this._curPageObj.pageIndex == 0 && this._rangeStart != 0:
        return 0;
      case this._curPageObj.pageIndex > this._rangeEnd:
        return this._curPageObj.pageIndex + this.inc > this.lastPageIndex
          ? this.lastPageIndex - this.inc * 2
          : this._curPageObj.pageIndex - this.inc;
      case this._curPageObj.pageIndex > this._curPageObj.previousPageIndex &&
        this._curPageObj.pageIndex > middleIndex &&
        this._rangeEnd < this.lastPageIndex:
        return this._rangeStart + 1;
      case this._curPageObj.pageIndex < this._curPageObj.previousPageIndex &&
        this._curPageObj.pageIndex < middleIndex &&
        this._rangeStart > 0:
        return this._rangeStart - 1;
      default:
        return this._rangeStart;
    }
  }
  //Helpter function to calculate end of button range
  private calcRangeEnd(middleIndex: number): number {
    switch (true) {
      case this._curPageObj.pageIndex == 0 &&
        this._rangeEnd != this._showTotalPages:
        return this._showTotalPages - 1;
      case this._curPageObj.pageIndex > this._rangeEnd:
        return this._curPageObj.pageIndex + this.inc > this.lastPageIndex
          ? this.lastPageIndex
          : this._curPageObj.pageIndex + 1;
      case this._curPageObj.pageIndex > this._curPageObj.previousPageIndex &&
        this._curPageObj.pageIndex > middleIndex &&
        this._rangeEnd < this.lastPageIndex:
        return this._rangeEnd + 1;
      case this._curPageObj.pageIndex < this._curPageObj.previousPageIndex &&
        this._curPageObj.pageIndex < middleIndex &&
        this._rangeStart >= 0 &&
        this._rangeEnd > this._showTotalPages - 1:
        return this._rangeEnd - 1;
      default:
        return this._rangeEnd;
    }
  }
  //Helper function to switch page on non first, last, next and previous buttons only.
  private switchPage(i: number): void {
    console.log('switch', i);
    const previousPageIndex = this.matPag.pageIndex;
    this.matPag.pageIndex = i;
    this.matPag['_emitPageEvent'](previousPageIndex);
    this.initPageRange();
  }
  //Initialize default state after view init
  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._rangeStart = 0;
    this._rangeEnd = this._showTotalPages - 1;
    this.initPageRange();
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8holwx-ob2az3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstyle-paginator.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmaterial-module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-pagination-example.html,src%2Fstyles.scss)

Comment: some looks like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787342/how-can-i-style-mat-paginator-angular-as-shown/70962395#70962395)?

Answer (score 0):

I was recently have the same problem of trying to change the mat-paginator styling. Here is the result of what I was able to achieve.

[Pagination Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3PP8.png)

[Here is a GIF how the solution looks line in production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rve6i.gif)

I have create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jab6ez?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fglobal_styles.css,src%2Fbubble-pagination.directive.ts,src%2Fsimple-table%2Fsimple-table.component.html&title=Angular%20Starter) example where you can play around with it.

I wrote down my experiences in [Angular: MatPaginator Custom Styling](https://dev.to/krivanek06/angular-matpaginator-custom-styling-dkb)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34734074)