# How to use Angular Material Paginator with a simple array of objects?

Tags: angular, angular-material, pagination, angular-material-paginator

I have checked every question in SO about how to use Angular Paginator with normal, not-material components. But somehow I struggle to understand how to do it correctly. I just have an array of objects and show them in my frontend like this:

[image]

this is my component.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image" *ngFor="let imageOrFile of imagesAndFiles">
    <dispo-einsatz-dokumente-gallery-image-item
      [image]="imageOrFile"
    ></dispo-einsatz-dokumente-gallery-image-item>
  </div>
</div>

<mat-paginator
  #paginator
  [pageSize]="5"
  [length]="9"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 10, 20, 50, 100]"
></mat-paginator>
```

and my component.ts:

```
export class DokumenteGalleryComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  imagesAndFiles: any[] = [];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true })
  paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Now I just cant get my head around on how to connect the pagination with the cards from the picture above, with the array `imagesAndFiles`?

Can someone enlighten me how to use it correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70543443/how-can-use-mat-paginator-for-paging-a-custom-card-based-component-into-parent-c/70551270#70551270