# How to transform a angular table row to a table of mat-card

Tags: angular, typescript, material-ui, grid, mat-card

So I have a table in my angular project, basic table, with pagination etc...There is a small code snippet of the table :

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Page top section -->
    <div id="adapter-view-grid" class="col">
        <mat-card>
            <mat-card-content>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <form [formGroup]="filterGrid">
                            <mat-form-field class="w-25">
                                <input matInput
                                       formControlName="filter"
                                       [placeholder]="'Filter'"
                                       >

                                <button *ngIf="filterGrid.controls.filter.value"
                                        mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear"
                                        (click)="filterGrid.controls.filter.setValue('')">
                                    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                                </button>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <table mat-table
                               matSort
                               [dataSource]="dataSource"
                               matSortActive="item_id"
                               matSortDirection="desc"
                               matSortDisableClear
                               class="mat-elevation-z8 w-100">


                          <ng-container matColumnDef="station_abbr">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{'Station'}}</th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.abbr}} </td>
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container matColumnDef="since">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{'Since'}}</th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.since | date:'medium'}} </td>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="till">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{'Till'}}</th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.till | date:'medium' }} </td>
                            </ng-container>


                            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row;
                                columns: displayedColumns;"
                                class="example-element-row">
<!--                                [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex === row}"-->
<!--                                (click)="onRowClicked(row)"></tr>-->
                        </table>


                        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100]"
                                       showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

My goal is that I want to replace the actual table by grid of card.
So 1 card by 'element.abbr' and display it in row. I've seen that I can use card with ngFor.
I am not very sure on which data i need to use from the actual table to convert it to a card.

Any advices or hint are welcome :)

Thanks

user ngFor with element, and use element.abbr as mat-header

Comment: A mat-paginator can be used "standalone" (see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70543443/how-can-use-mat-paginator-for-paging-a-custom-card-based-component-into-parent-c/70551270#70551270)). To use the "filter" you can loop over datasource.filteredData, so the final will be more like to: `datasource.filteredData|slice:(paginator.pageIndex*paginator.pageSize):((paginator.pageIndex+1)*paginator.pageSize)`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but can you be more explicit ?
I will filter the data by using  element.attr and display it in mat-card ? If yes, how to proceed.